# Segmentation fault while running the following code

Tags: python, pypdf, pyttsx3

I want to convert the numpy.pdf file to audio format and play along but I keep getting segmentation fault.
I posted wrong code before.Here is the actual one.It worked if I play it but get segmentation error while
saving the file outside the loop and the loops never stops if I tried to save the file inside the loop or
it would just steps after sometime.Help would be appreciated.I am just begning my python carer.

```
import pyttsx3 
import PyPDF2
engine = pyttsx3.init()
user_file = input("Plz enter filename ")
file_object = open(user_file, 'rb')
reader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(file_object)
count = reader.numPages
new_page = []
format_choose = int(input("Enter 1 or 2")
if format_choose == 1:
    user_input = int(input("Enter the page to begin.> "))
    for i in range(count):
        page = reader.getPage(i)
        new_page.append(page.extractText())
        text = "".join(new_page)
        engine.setProperty('rate', 125)
        engine.say(text)
        engine.runAndWait()
elif format_choose == 2:
    output_file = input("Enter the file name")
    for i in range(count):
        page = reader.getPage(i)
        new_page.append(page.extractText())
        text = "".join(new_page)
        engine.setProperty('rate', 125)
        engine.save_to_file(text, output_file)
        engine.runAndWait()
```

Comment: You need to indent the Try and Except statement if you want them to be in the for loop.

Comment: which line is causing the segfault?

Comment: @MichealChen although the code seemed to be indented improperly, I dont think that would cause a segfault.

Comment: yedpodtrzitko, I know that. That’s why I didn’t post that comment as an answer. I was just noticing that his code was improperly indented